# Table with tabular goes outside of page and is not centered when minipage is added to adjustbox

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, minipage, scaling, adjustbox

I am trying to have my table fit the text width and be centered in the middle. Without minipage it works as intended but when I add a minipage to the adjustbox (since I need the caption and potential notes to also scale) the table goes outside of the right of the page. When I scale it down to not overflow it does not align in the middle. For other tables this code work fine but I can't figure out how to fix this.

```
\label{finsum} 
\caption{Financial Variables} 
\begin{adjustbox}{scale=1, max width = \textwidth , minipage=\textwidth} \centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
 \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Median earnings & 700 & 39,910.940 & 4,870.070 & 31,937 & 36,159.2 & 43,288.8 & 53,208 \\ 
Poverty rate & 700 & 12.995 & 2.951 & 6.590 & 10.848 & 15.145 & 22.100 \\ 
Households on public assistance & 700 & 2.556 & 0.935 & 1.080 & 1.890 & 3.080 & 6.860 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: The `\label` statement should be placed after, not before, the `\caption` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Some comments:

- Please provide a *full* MWE (compilable, small, reproduces (un)wanted behavior).
- I simply pivoted your tabular.
- Have a look at my usage of `siunitx`' `S` column type to align numbers at the decimal point.
- I used `booktabs` which provide `top-/mid-/bottomrule` for professional rules with appropriate spacing.
- See how to use `label` and `caption`.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{Financial Variables} 
        \label{finsum2}
        \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=5.3]S[table-format=3.3]S[table-format=4.3]}
            \toprule
            Statistic & {Median earnings} & {Poverty rate} & {\parbox{2.7cm}{Households on\\public assistance}} \\ \midrule
            $N$      &   700     &  700     &  700     \\
            Mean     & 39910.940 &   12.995 &    2.556 \\
            St. Dev. &  4870.070 &    2.951 &    0.935 \\
            Min      & 31937.000 &    6.590 &    1.080 \\
            Pctl(25) & 36159.200 &   10.848 &    1.890 \\
            Pctl(75) & 43288.800 &   15.145 &    3.080 \\
            Max      & 53208.000 &   22.100 & 6860.000 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    Important: Put \texttt{label} \emph{after} \texttt{caption}: See \ref{finsum} which does not work and \ref{finsum2} which refers to the table.
\end{document}
```